# Groebner basis and syzygy

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

I am not familiar with polynomial ring.

Suppose we have an ideal $\langle f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n \rangle$ of the polynomial ring $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$. Suppose there is some syzygy relation between the generators $f_i$.

Of course one wants to make the basis really independent, namely to get rid of the syzygy relation.

Is this always possible with the Groebner basis?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\langle f_1, \ldots, f_n \rangle$ is usually not a free $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$-module, then there is usually no such basis.  Consider for example $\langle x, y \rangle \trianglelefteq k[x,y]$. Then $yx - xy = 0$, so there is a $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$-linear relation, i.e., a syzygy, between the generators $x, y$.  Similarly, for any generators $f_1, f_2$ of $\langle x, y \rangle$, we have $f_2 f_1 - f_1 f_2 = 0$.  Since $\langle x,y \rangle$ can't be generated by fewer than $2$ elements, this shows that there is no $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$-basis for $\langle x, y \rangle$.

The way you "get rid" of syzygies is by using [free resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28algebra%29#Free.2C_projective.2C_injective.2C_and_flat_resolutions) and [Hilbert's Syzygy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_syzygy_theorem).

Comment: How could one be so crazy to consider $f_1 f_2 - f_2 f_1 =0$ as a syzygy? This is trivial.

Comment: @kaiser What is your definition of a syzygy?  Mine is an $R$-linear relation of the generators of $M$, which agrees with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygy_%28mathematics%29).  Actually, my example is exactly the same as in [this expository paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200604/what-is.pdf).